# how to separate tasks in javax.swing.Timer?

Tags: java, timer

i am writing a program inorder to accomplish 3 tasks :

1. downloads xml files from remote folder to a local folder using ftp.
2. read and treat the files.
3. delete the files from the local folder.

i used javax.swing.Timer to repeat that periodically.

i want to prevent task 2 from starting until task one finish and prevent task 3 from starting until task 2 finish.

how can i achieve that

thnks

here is my code :

```
new javax.swing.Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   FTPFileDownloader ftpdown = new FTPFileDownloader();
   try {
    ftpdown.downloadFiles(Configuration.array.get(0), Configuration.array.get(3), Configuration.array.get(4), Configuration.array.get(5), Configuration.array.get(6));
} catch (IOException e2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

  XmlToDB xmldb=new XmlToDB();   
        ReadFilesFromFolder readfiles=new ReadFilesFromFolder();
        File file=new File("C:\\FTP_CLIENT_DIRECTORY\\");
        ArrayList<File> output=readfiles.listFilesForFolder(file, true, "");
        ArrayList<String> ss = null;
        try {
            ss = xmldb.XMLtoString(output);
            int nbrechang=xmldb.insert(ss);
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException E) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            E.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

            }
      }
  }

 }).start();
```

Comment: `Timer` may not be your best choice, a single threaded `Executor` would probably be better.  If you need to update the UI as part of your work, you can actually use a `SwingWorker` with the `Executor` API

Comment: i read about ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor i think it can solve my problem but i don't know how to use it in my case, can you give me a simple example so i can update my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, you could use a single threaded executor to stage the request, for example...

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FTPFileDownloader ftpdown = new FTPFileDownloader();
        try {
            ftpdown.downloadFiles(Configuration.array.get(0), Configuration.array.get(3), Configuration.array.get(4), Configuration.array.get(5), Configuration.array.get(6));
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        XmlToDB xmldb = new XmlToDB();
        ReadFilesFromFolder readfiles = new ReadFilesFromFolder();
        File file = new File("C:\\FTP_CLIENT_DIRECTORY\\");
        ArrayList<File> output = readfiles.listFilesForFolder(file, true, "");
        ArrayList<String> ss = null;
        try {
            ss = xmldb.XMLtoString(output);
            int nbrechang = xmldb.insert(ss);
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException E) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

This does assume you're not updating a Swing based UI (I couldn't find any evidence)

You could then simply use a `java.util.Timer` to schedule a download request on the `Executor`, which won't be executed until all other previous tasks in the queue have been completed

```
Timer timer = new Timer("Download Timer");
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        executor.execute(new DownloadRunnable());
    }
}, 0, TIMER_DELAY);
```

Where `DownloadRunnable` is simply a class of your `Runnable` implementation

```
public class DownloadRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FTPFileDownloader ftpdown = new FTPFileDownloader();
        try {
            ftpdown.downloadFiles(Configuration.array.get(0), Configuration.array.get(3), Configuration.array.get(4), Configuration.array.get(5), Configuration.array.get(6));
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        XmlToDB xmldb = new XmlToDB();
        ReadFilesFromFolder readfiles = new ReadFilesFromFolder();
        File file = new File("C:\\FTP_CLIENT_DIRECTORY\\");
        ArrayList<File> output = readfiles.listFilesForFolder(file, true, "");
        ArrayList<String> ss = null;
        try {
            ss = xmldb.XMLtoString(output);
            int nbrechang = xmldb.insert(ss);
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException E) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: yes actually i am updating a Swing based UI i thought that there is no difference !

Comment: The you could actually use a `SwingWorker`, but I didn't really see anywhere in your code you might have been interacting with a UI.  Swing is a single threaded environment, Swing `Timer` executes the `ActionListener` within the context of the EDT, which is kind of bad for what you are doing, this approach will use a separate thread, which means you need to take special care and technquies when updating the UI

Comment: i dont know what you really meant by interaction with UI because there is jlabel that changes its value depending on the value of **nbrechang** in the timer

Comment: @HaiderRzig Which variable is the `JLabel`, all I have a is a out-of-context piece of code which is neither compilable or runnable, so I'm just make guesses

Comment: that because i didn't put the hole code, never mind it works fine now thanks

Comment: can you give me an example about how to use **SwingWorker** with single thread in my case !!